# Ajax json and parameters from a login form

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html, jquery-mobile

My question is as follows:

I am creating a login for a jquery mobile application. I am doing this by a standard html login form. After i click the submit button, i am checking if the username and password provided are correct. I check this by using Ajax and json. Now the problem is as follows, if i do the following:

```
function authenticate(userName, password1) {

                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
                        url: "http://notgiven",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        //json object to sent to the authentication url
                        //data: {"username": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"},
                     data: { username: "user1", password: "test1" },,
                        success: function (data) {
                            //do any process for successful authentication here
                            alert('Login status: ' + data.status);
                        }
                     })
                };
```

Then i get a success,

But if i want to get the parameters from my fields and do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                                  //event handler for submit button
                                  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                                                        //collect userName and password entered by users
                                                        var userName = $("#username").val();
                                                        var password = $("#password").val();


                                                        });

                });


                function authenticate(userName, password1) {

                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
                        url: "http://notgiven",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        //json object to sent to the authentication url
                        //data: '{"username": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
                      data: '{username: userName, password: password1 }',
                        success: function (data) {
                            //do any process for successful authentication here
                            alert('Login status: ' + data.status);
                        }
                     })
                };
```

Then i get a fail...
Any one know why???

**ANSWER:****ANSWER:**ANSWER:**ANSWER:**

I have put : authenticate(userName,password);
into the click function as Thrustmaster said.
Done this because otherwise the data of username and password while clicking are going out of scope as Andrew said.

I've also put return false; at the .click function so that i can click the button more than once(and still getting results of function authenticate).

THNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't username and password are out of scope after the click event. Or I got my closures wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `authenticate(..)` from the `.click(..)` event.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var userName = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    authenticate(userName,password);
);
```

and inside `authenticate(..)` it should be:

```
data: {username: userName, password: password1},
```

Comment: I know, i do this with the button: <input id="btnSubmit" onclick="authenticate()" type="submit" value="Login" data-role="button"  />

Comment: Its a bad idea to mix jQuery's `.click(..)` and HTML `onclick`. Stick with jQuery, and modify the said line inside `authenticate (..)`

Comment: I do that on purpose, because if someone types in a wrong username/password then if he clicks the button again, it wont activate the function.

Comment: and for the data part, i already tried that, doesnt work either.

Comment: Ok because of the answer of andrew douglas, i saw that my values where out of scope, so i put the authenticate back in the click event again. But now if i want to click a second time it doesnt call the function do you know why?

Comment: fixed this: need to put return false; in the click function

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the values of username and password:

```
data: '{username: userName, password: password1 }',
```

change it to:

```
data: {'username': userName, 'password': password1 },
```